# An exception in splitting

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to split an IP address by ".". But code is generating an exception.

```
Exception Message : "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at decimaltobinary.DecimalToBinary.main".
```

Help me to solve. Here is my Code.

```
 String[] ipAddresses=IP.split(".");
 String ip1=ipAddresses[0];
 String ip2=ipAddresses[1];
 String ip3=ipAddresses[2];
 String ip4=ipAddresses[3];
```

Comment: You haven't included all the code. Where is `IP` defined?

Comment: This means that there are no elements in your array. Print the original value of IP before spliting.

Comment: i think you need to escape `.`

Comment: i think you should use `'.'` instead of `"."` since you should split by a char, not a string

Comment: Why does this have the [scala] tag?

Answer (score 3):

`.` is special character in regular expressions. Try:

`IP.split("\\.");`

Comment: @Fast Snail, it is actually. My bad!

Answer (score 1):

In a regex, the token `.` means to match on any character. If you want to match the character literal `.`, you need to split on the regex `\.`.

This means that the actual String must represent `\.` so you'll have to do `.split("\\.")`.

Answer (score 0):

try with `(\\.)` ie `String[] ipAddresses=IP.split("\\.")`
that will give you

```
String[] ipAddresses=IP.split("\\.");
 String ip1=ipAddresses[0];
 String ip2=ipAddresses[1];
 String ip3=ipAddresses[2];
 String ip4=ipAddresses[3];
```

it should be work.